# Substituir números que estão dentro de uma palavra

Tags: python, regex

Desejo remover números em meio à letras, porém não desejo remover todos os números do texto, exemplo:

```
Vini12cius
```

Quero transformar em `Vinicius`, mas sem alterar um possível CPF que virá após, criei o seguinte regex:

```
r = re.sub(r'([0-9])','',"")
```

Porém, ele elimina **todos** os números do texto, mesmo os que não estejam entre caracteres, também tentei:

```
r = re.sub(r'([a-z]*[0-9]*[a-z])','',"")
```

Mas também não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Mantendo os `[a-z]` dentro dos parenteses, você os captura junto, fazendo que sejam, também, substituídos. Reveja o seu grupo de captura. Aproveitando, e se foram coisas como "123foo" ou "foo123"? Deve substituir ou não?

Comment: sim, nestes casos podem ser removidos, o meu problema está nos números que estão sozinhos, pois não desejo que sejam removidos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu prefiro fazer isso com uma função de substituição:

```
>>> def f(m):
...     text = m.group()
...     if text.isdigit(): # se for tudo digito
...         return text
...     else:
...         return re.sub(r'\d', '', text)
... 
>>> re.sub(r'\w+', f, '4lfr3do rodr1g0 marc05 12345')
'lfrdo rodrg marc 12345'
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, deu certo!!

Comment: Sabe como eu poderia fazer agora se quisesse realizar o contrário? Ex: 1234678ab910 e transformar em : 12345678910

Comment: Seria só trocar `r'\d'` por `r'\D'` @HVLopes

Comment: Perfeito, agradeço amigo

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar esta Expressão Regular: `\d+(?=[a-zA-Z]+)|(?<=[a-zA-Z])\d+`

Em que a demo do [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uUStvg/4) pode ser vista.

#### Código

```
import re


testes = ("Vini12cius 000.000.000-00",
            "Vini12cius 00000000000",
            "Vinicius12 00000000000",
            "12Vinicius 00000000000",
            "000.000.000-00 Vini12cius",
            "00000000000 Vini12cius",
            "00000000000 Vinicius12",
            "00000000000 12Vinicius")


padrao_regex = re.compile(r"\d+(?=[a-zA-Z]+)|(?<=[a-zA-Z])\d+")
substituicoes = [re.sub(padrao_regex, "", elemento_teste) for elemento_teste in testes]
if substituicoes:
    for substituicao in substituicoes:
        print(substituicao)
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/3ia2zd)

Comment: Obrigado!! também funcionou , agradeço !!